# how to determine $A^{15}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A$ be the $3\times 3$ matrix such that ,for any $v \in \Bbb R^3,Av$ gives the projection of $v$ onto the plane $x+y+z=0$. Determine $A^{15}$.

I think I know $A^{15}=PD^{15} P^{-1}$. But I don't know how to get the $P$ and $D$.

Comment: What is the definition of a projection?

Comment: As $A$ is a projection, you have $A^2=A$, so $A^{15}=A$. But if you want to calculate $A$ explicitly, you need to know what kind of projection. Orthogonal projection?

Comment: If it is a projection then $A^{15}=A$.

Comment: check what it is doing to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
Av=v-(v,u)u,
$$
where $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$.

Then $A^2v=A(v-(v,u)u)=Av-(v,u)Au=Av$, and thus 
$$
A^{15}v=Av=v-(v,u)u=(v_1,v_2,v_3)-\frac{1}{3}(v_1+v_2+v_3)(1,1,1).
$$
Hence
$$
A=A^{15}=\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{2}{3} &-\frac{1}{3} &-\frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{3} &\frac{2}{3} &-\frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{3} &-\frac{1}{3} &\frac{2}{3}
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Comment: why u=1/√3 (1,1,1).?

Comment: Shouldn't $Av$ be $(v,u)u$ instead of $v-(v,u)u$ (assuming $A$ is supposed to be orthogonal)?

Comment: @cecily: I have divide by $\sqrt{3}$ to make to vector unit length.